# How to Restore Session Menu to Unity Panel?

Tags: unity, 11.10, panel, indicator

For reason(s) yet unknown, the Session Indicator has disappeared from my Unity Panel (ver. 11.10.)  Short of reinstalling, is there a way the Session Indicator can be restored, perhaps through a command issued to gsettings? (I'm new to Ubuntu and still learning.)

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can alter the settings related to indicator-session using dconf-editor. To install dconf-editor, search for dconf tool in the software center or run this command in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
```

In dconf-tools, you can configure the indicator-session as you wish.

[image]

Comment: Appreciate the fast response. I've tried configuring the key-values for indicator-session using dconf-tools, however I've not had any luck thus far in restoring the indicator. I'm wondering if perhaps there is another way this must be done?

Answer (score 1):

Try this - 
Right click in the desktop screen > Change Desktop Background

At the bottom is a dropdown for Theme, switch from your current selection to something else & then back again, ie. - from Ambiance to Radiance, back to Ambiance