# Problem with session indicator

Tags: indicator, session

I'm using Unity DE.
I removed packagekit: `apt-get remove packagekit*` (OK. it's bad idea...)
After this action a lost session indicator on top right panel:

[image]

I know, I remove package for session, but I don't know what packet..

p.s.
I have some troubles in KDE, can't restart, shutdown, logout, etc

Comment: Hi Sergey, are you using Unity or KDE? Your screenshot is of Unity. If your goal is to just restore your session indicator see [these](http://askubuntu.com/q/142561/12864) [two](http://askubuntu.com/q/68478/12864) similar questions.

Comment: I use Unity and install KDE as second DE. I find solution: reinstall indicator-session.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer then accept it to mark this as solved. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP reported solving the problem (in comments) by reinstalling the [indicator-session [image: Install indicator-session]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/indicator-session) package.

(One way to do that is to run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get --purge --reinstall install indicator-session`.)